# How to separate two IP Pools for the single LAN network

Tags: ip, static-ip, pool

I want to create two IP pools in my private network. I want to do this so that the IP cameras in my network are separated and the data devices(PC's, AP's, IP Phones) are separated. But I'm doing all this on a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your router you can use access control or VLANS.With ACL's you can allow or disable traffic to the different pools.

Answer (score 0):

To create two separate IP pools in your private network, you'll need to configure your network devices, such as your router or DHCP server, to assign different IP address ranges to the two groups of devices (IP cameras and data devices). Since you mentioned that you're using static IP addresses, you'll need to manually assign IP addresses to your devices within these specified ranges. Here are the general steps:

Define IP Address Ranges:

Decide on two distinct IP address ranges for your IP cameras and data devices. For example:
IP Cameras: 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.50
Data Devices: 192.168.1.51 to 192.168.1.100
Assign Static IPs to Devices:

Manually assign static IP addresses to your devices based on the defined ranges. This is typically done on each device's network settings.
Configure DHCP Server (Optional):

If you have a DHCP server in your network (like a router), you can configure it to assign specific IP ranges to devices based on their MAC addresses.
Set up two DHCP pools, each with its own IP range, and specify the devices (based on MAC addresses) that should receive IPs from each pool.
Configure VLANs (Optional):

If your network devices support VLANs, you can create two separate VLANs for IP cameras and data devices. This provides a logical separation at the network level.
Subnetting (Optional):

If you want to achieve physical separation, you might consider subnetting. This involves dividing your network into subnets with different IP ranges. This can be more complex and may require additional routing configuration.
Router/Firewall Configuration:

Ensure that your router or firewall is configured to allow communication between devices in the same group and restrict communication between groups if desired.
Verification:

Verify that devices are assigned IP addresses within the correct ranges and that they can communicate within their respective groups.
Remember that the exact steps for these configurations can vary depending on your network equipment and its capabilities. If you're unsure or need more specific guidance, refer to the documentation of your router, DHCP server, or other networking devices, or consult with your network administrator. If you provide more details about your network equipment, I can offer more specific instructions.